# Can I sort in excel but read the cell values from right to left?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have an excel worksheet list of names and email addresses.   Some of the email addresses, however, are cutoff on the right and have "...".

For example: some email addresses are "test@test_user...".

How can I sort this list, reading the cell values from right to left so I can find the "..." and/or the proper ".com".

Comment: Were they entered like this, or is it just excel that doesn't fully show it because the cell is too small? As in: if you make the column wider, will they show normally?

Comment: entered like this.  someone copied a column out of a crm instead of exporting to a csv.

Answer (score 3):

As I am not sure what version of Excel you are using, in Excel 2010 (but,it is similar in other versions):

- Highlight your data
- go to `Data`
- select `Sort`
- Once the Sorting dialog box opens, go to `Options` (figure 1) and there, you can select the radio box labelled `left to right` (figure 2):

*figure 1*

[image]

*figure 2*

[image]

Make sure the correct row is selected in `row`, in the `Sort On` menu, select `Values` and in the `Order` menu, select `Custom Lists` (figure 3)

*figure 3*

[image]

Select `NEW LIST` and then enter your values.